# Convert a struct to vector of bytes

Tags: c++, vector, struct

In my C++ application I have this struct

```
typedef struct 
{
int a;
int b;
char *c
}MyStruct
```

and I have this instance:

```
MyStruct s;
```

Also I have this definition:

```
vector<byte> buffer;
```

I would like to insert\convert the `s` struct to the buffer vector.

What is the best way to do it in C++?

Thanks.

Comment: `vector<byte> buffer(sizeof(s)); memcpy(&buffer[0] &s, sizeof(s));`

Comment: Are you trying to do serialization? Do you care about endianness? Padding? Alignment?

Comment: and what do you want to do with your `char* c`? Should you copy its content? by the way, your code doesn't look like C++

Comment: Careful, if you are doing serialization keep in mind that the char* pointer is not going to be valid anymore in another process.

Answer (score 17):

The best way is by using the [range copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) and a low-level cast to retrieve a pointer to the memory of the structure:

```
auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&s);
auto buffer = vector<byte>(ptr, ptr + sizeof s);
```

To go the other way, you can just cast the byte buffer to the target type (but it needs to be the *same* type, otherwise you’re violating [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)):

```
auto p_obj = reinterpret_cast<obj_t*>(&buffer[0]);
```

However, for indices ≠ 0 (and I guess *technically* also for index = 0, but this seems unlikely) beware of mismatching [memory alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). A safer way is therefore to first copy the buffer into a [properly aligned storage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage), and to access pointers from there.

Comment: Nice answer. I have a different question: I need to do the "other way around": I have a vector<unsigned char> which is filled with values (it's size is , say 100) , and I wish to compare the first 8 bytes of the vector with a given struct , that defined as follows: 
 struct BlockInfoHeader
 {
  uint32_t magicHeader;
  uint32_t thread;
  uint64_t timestamp; // in microseconds since start of run
  uint64_t offset;
  uint32_t len;
  uint32_t blockIndex;
  uint32_t writeIndex;
  uint32_t seed;
 }; In order to compare the first 8 bytes of the vector with some values given in advance.

Comment: @GuyAvraham, please ask a new question, if you still have that doubt.